# Special characters in JSON property

Tags: java, jackson

I have JSON which has colon (`:`) in property. Now I am wondering how to map this property name with java class property.

I tried `@JsonProperty("viacom:VideoDuration")` but it is not working.

Here is the sample json

```
{
       "shortTitle": "Teen Wolf",
       "viacom:VideoDuration": "20h:30m",
       "viacom:metadataLanguage": "en",
       "viacom:contentType": "franchise",
       "viacom:urlKey": "http://urlkey.com",
       "viacom:vmid":"cee71f4a-ec7d-4ccd-a10d-9bf6b7506d352",
       "viacom:originLanguage":"en"
}
```

> Note : I do not have option to rename the `json` `property` name to something else.

Comment: I don't see `viacom:VideoDuration` property in your sample json maybe this is a problem?

Comment: Its just an example. Anyway I have updated the JSON.

Comment: What does "is not working" mean? What happens? Any error message?

Comment: OK, first of all try escape colon char in this way `@JsonProperty("viacom\:VideoDuration")` and let us know if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Probably it's a problem of a library you are using or its version.
I've just created a simple test and it has ran properly.

Test class:

```
public class TestClass {

  private String valueStr;
  @JsonProperty("test:prop")
  private String testProp;

  public String getValueStr() {
    return valueStr;
  }

  public void setValueStr(String valueStr) {
    this.valueStr = valueStr;
  }

  public String getTestProp() {
    return testProp;
  }

  public void setTestProp(String testProp) {
    this.testProp = testProp;
  }
}
```

And test:

```
@Test
  public void test()
      throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {

    String test = "{\r\n" +
        "       \"test:prop\": \"Teen Wolf\",\r\n" +
        "       \"valueS\": \"franchise\"\r\n" +
        "}";

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    TestClass data = mapper.readValue(test, TestClass.class);
    Assert.assertTrue("expected Teen Wolf, actual=" + data.getTestProp(),
        Objects.equals("Teen Wolf", data.getTestProp()));
  }
```

I've used `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper` from `com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.8.8\jackson-databind-2.8.8.jar`

By the way which type the `"viacom:VideoDuration"` property is in the java class? I mean what if the problem not in the property name but in the value? It also has a colon and you are trying to deserialize it in the wrong way?